# Introducir en una array/objeto el resultado de una función que devuelve un objeto con datos

Tags: javascript, array, objeto

Tengo una función llamada Moda que hace el cálculo Moda de ciertos numeros que yo mismo introduzco. Tengo dos problemas:

1. Tengo que introducir dos valores en el objeto/array oModa. Tengo que introducir el numero que es el que contiene la array aValores[i], y tambien tengo que introducir la freciencia que es el contador. Eso como se ve, lo he ido haciendo tras acabar el for del array aValores. Pero creo que eso no me lo almacena todo, solo los ultimos dos valores. Quiero almacenar todos los valores en ese objeto.
2. Esos valores en el objeto oModa, tengo que devolverlos, tanto los valores como sus propiedades: numero/frecuencia. Y lo que quiero es coger ese return en una variable objeto, en este caso la he llamado aPrueba. Pero cuando lo ejecuto dice que prueba no es iterable. Mi problema es que no se como introducir los datos de ese return en esa variable.
   Aquí os dejo el código. Muchas gracias y un saludo.

```js
function Moda(...aValores){
    var oModa={};
    
    var intContador=0;
    var intPosicionArray=0;
    
    if(aValores.length===0)//está vacía
        return oModa=[];//dsevolverá un array vacía
    
    for (let valoresArrayValores of aValores){
        intPosicionArray++;//para el primer valor, ya estamos en la primera posicion
        valoresArrayValores=parseFloat(valoresArrayValores);//con esto solucionamo el problema de "";
        if(isNaN(valoresArrayValores))
            throw "el argumento "+intPosicionArray+" no es numérico";
      }    
        for(let i=0; i<aValores.length;i++){
            for (let j = 0; j <aValores.length; j++) {
                if(parseFloat(aValores[i])===parseFloat(aValores[j])){//minimo entrará una vez
                    intContador++;
                }
            }
            oModa={
                numero: parseFloat(aValores[i]),
                frecuencia: intContador
            };
            for(let x in oModa)
                console.log(oModa);
            
            intContador=0;//para evaluar el siguiente numero
        }
    return oModa;
}

var aValorcitos=[1,2,3,5,6,3];
var aPrueba={};
aPrueba=Moda(...aValorcitos);
for(let i of aPrueba){
    alert(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bueno si entendí bien tu consulta quieres al final tener un array con muchos objetos que representen esa Moda, acá el tema es que tu variable oModa la creas y tratas como un objeto, no como un array de objetos por ello al final cuando la retornas y tratas de iterar como si fuese un array te da problemas. De nuevo si lo que quieres es un array entonces hay que primero definir oModa como un array y luego ir pusheando cada uno de los elementos Moda que vas creando en el mismo:

```js
function Moda(...aValores){
    var oModa=[];
    
    var intContador=0;
    var intPosicionArray=0;
    
    if(aValores.length===0)//está vacía
        return oModa=[];//dsevolverá un array vacía
    
    for (let valoresArrayValores of aValores){
        intPosicionArray++;//para el primer valor, ya estamos en la primera posicion
        valoresArrayValores=parseFloat(valoresArrayValores);//con esto solucionamo el problema de "";
        if(isNaN(valoresArrayValores))
            throw "el argumento "+intPosicionArray+" no es numérico";
      }    
        for(let i=0; i<aValores.length;i++){
            for (let j = 0; j <aValores.length; j++) {
                if(parseFloat(aValores[i])===parseFloat(aValores[j])){//minimo entrará una vez
                    intContador++;
                }
            }
            oModa.push({
                numero: parseFloat(aValores[i]),
                frecuencia: intContador
            });
            
            intContador=0;//para evaluar el siguiente numero
        }
    return oModa;
}

var aValorcitos=[1,2,3,5,6,3];
var aPrueba={};
aPrueba=Moda(...aValorcitos);
for(let i of aPrueba){
    console.log(i.numero+'   '+i.frecuencia)
}
```

Al final la variable aPrueba va a tener el array que retorna la función Moda y ese array si es iterable, además como es un array de objetos cada "i" del ciclo será uno de esos objetos "Moda" por ende debemos acceder a las propiedades utiliando "."

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. Finalmente encontre la solución, pero lo que tu me comentas me parece mucho mejor. Mi solucion fue hacer push a una array, pero antes introducir los datos a un objeto, pero veo que tu lo haces todo junto, así que me quedo con lo tuyo. Muchas gracias